# Trying to load large video but getting '503 Service Unavailable'

Tags: javascript, php, video-streaming, video.js, http-status-code-503

I'm having a problem loading a large video into the browser. I have a `video.php` file, which creates a `$token` to access the product specified in `$_GET['product']` and then [`video.js`](https://videojs.com) requests access to the video files.

```
<video id="viewer"
class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "metadata" }'
height="500" width="1000" disablePictureInPicture controls="disabled">
  <source src="videostream?type=m3u8&path=<?php echo $token; ?>/prog_index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

The server should then return the chunks of the video. The videos are stored like this:

```
private
- products
-- 1
--- prog_index.m3u8
--- fileSequence0.ts
--- fileSequence1.ts
--- fileSequence2.ts
--- and so on...
```

It duplicates the folder to `tmp` with the name of the folder is the token. Let's say the token was `1234123412341234`:

```
private
- tmp
-- 1234123412341234
--- prog_index.m3u8
--- fileSequence0.ts
--- fileSequence1.ts
--- fileSequence2.ts
--- and so on...
```

And the files get deleted as they are loaded.

**When I try to access `mysite.com/video.php?product=1`, I get 503 Service Unavailable.**

The total size of the video files are about 1-2GB big and I'm using GoDaddy hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you get in the error log ?

Comment: @MelvynMarigny There was nothing in the error log.

Comment: 503 errors **always** land in the error log unless explicitly suppressed. What's in the access log?

Comment: @ximaera It's error 500s that always land in the error log, not 503s.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? If yes, shared hosting won't allow you to upload large/huge file or use high CPU/memory consumption. If you receive 503 error, it means that your application pool is stop working, this indicate that your hosting provider limit your application pool

Comment: @MarkSpencer I am using shared hosting, but the files have been segmented using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @MarkSpencer I am using shared hosting, but the files have been segmented using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @MarkSpencer I am using shared hosting, but the files have been segmented using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @TheWebDeveloperBlog I believe you can't upload large video files on shared hosting, it is prohibited. You may need to contact your provider about this issue. What you need to know is that your application pool stop working so you receive above error.

Comment: @MarkSpencer The files have been segmented into 10-second-each TS files. They are not 1 big file.

Comment: @TheWebDeveloperBlog I'm sorry, I'm not too sure, but you may need to discuss this issue with your current provider. Good luck, bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my PHP was timing out. My `php.ini` file had a `max_execution_time` of `600` (5 minutes), so when I changed the `max_execution_time` to `-1`, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Why are you Getting a 503 Error?

GoDaddy hosting throws a `503 ERROR` if either:

**a)** Your website met its maximum concurrent connection limit or

**b)** If your hosting account uses up all of its available resources (which is probably the case here since you mention having to load large video files exceeding 1 GB

### Resolution

#### Depending on your hosting account type the solution is as follows:

**Linux Hosting (cPanel):** End the PHP processes in your Linux Hosting account (for more info click [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/end-php-processes-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16119))

**Windows Hosting (Plesk):** Try [recycling your application pool](https://www.godaddy.com/help/recycle-your-application-pool-16131)

**Web Hosting (Linux):** End processes using  [Manage system process (Linux) in my Web & Classic Hosting account](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manage-system-process-linux-in-my-web-and-classic-hosting-account-5980)

**Web Hosting (Windows):** Try [Recycle your application pool(windows)](https://img4.wsimg.com/support/pdf/WebHosting/webhostingguide-041420.pdf)

### Another Possible Issue

**If you use WordPress** along with your website one of your plugins may be causing the issue. Try disabling and enabling all of them and enable them one at a time to see if they are causing the issue.

### Troubleshooting and prevention:

Make sure you have enough hard drive space whenever you load large videos so you don't get the `503 ERROR`!

**Hope this was helpful and I hope this solved your issue.**

*Note: Nothing showed in your error log since in essence there was no real error. Nothing went wrong in the code as you can see in the solutions above.*

Comment: When I login to cPanel, it shows up on the sidebar with the resources being used up, so I believe you are correct and it is 'b' that is causing the problem.

Comment: Is the physical memory being used up got to do with this. I tried loading my video, and then cPanel told me that the physical memory was nearly full.

Comment: I'm happy I was helpful

Comment: It probably is hard drive space.

Comment: Link no.3 redirects to Link no.1 and Link no.4 says that Classic hosting isn't available anymore. ???

Comment: I'm sorry - let me clarify. Link no. 1 has the same solution as 1 so it redirects to the same link. Link no. 4 I fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Just a question: Should I use the WordPress health checker? I do have a WordPress site running alongside it on the main domain. (My issue is happening on a subdomain.)

Comment: It depends. Are you attempting to run any other large videos on your main Wordpress site?. I mean - it never hurts to check up on your website...